# Error while creating custom metrics with 'monitoring_v3' for containers in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

We are getting the following error

> "One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were
>   written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured
>   for the metric.: timeSeries[0]"

when we tried to create container level metric in GKE. We are creating custom metric to update app_queue length for every second. It works well under normal case. But when the pods scales beyond 100 - we receive this error for some of the API calls and it is very high in number.

**Question:**
Is the any quota or setting we are missing? or some best practice of creating custom metrics?

**Stack trace:**

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Base-1.0-py3.6.egg/base/custom_metrics.py", line 63, in create_custom_metric
        client.create_time_series(project_name, [series])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/gapic/metric_service_client.py", line 775, in create_time_series
        request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 139, in __call__
        return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
        on_error=on_error,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
        return target()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 61, in error_remapped_callable
        six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric.: timeSeries[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hitting any quota limit, an error should be recorded in Stackdriver Logging. You may also visit your quota page to see if you are hitting any limits [Menu>IAM & admin>Quotas].

In terms of rules to follow, have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts)  for more insight on how to write data to custom metric type. A best practice when adding multiple data points to the same time series, is not to add them faster than once per min.